# index.js's console.log isn't being reached

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have an `index.js` file with a simple `console.log()` and it isn't being registered in the browser. I also noticed that bootstrap isn't running---I'm almost certain these two events are related, but I'm not sure how to properly diagnose the issues. I've tried moving code around, changing paths, looking for missing commas, etc., but to no avail.

I'm compiling files with `webpack.config.js` and as far as I'm concerned my code is being compiled correctly.

Any thoughts on this?

#### index.js:

```
import 'jquery';
import "./SiteAssets/scripts/addRow.js";
import "./RecruitmentTracking.css";

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.min.js';

console.log('this is index.js');

const root = document.createElement("div")
root.innerHTML = `<p>Hello Webpack.</p>`
document.body.appendChild(root)
```

#### webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack');
// const babel = require("@babel/core");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var $ = require("jquery");

var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    filename: 'RecruitmentTracking.txt',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {                                         
  entry: "./src/index.js", // "compile code in our entry point"
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js', // output a bundle in /dist"
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }, {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
    devServer: {
      disableHostCheck: true
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // this helps to browser to point to the exact file in the console, helps in debug
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      historyApiFallback: true // this prevents the default browser full page refresh on form submission and link change
    },    
  plugins: [
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "$": "jquery",
        "jQuery": "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
  ],  
}
```

#### package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "develop": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development"
  },
```

#### screencap:

[image]

Comment: can you share git link to your source code?

Comment: @divine Unfortunately, due to privacy reasons this project isn't on Github.